# Bitmap->image window form applications

Tags: c#, emgucv

I have problem in converting System.Drawing.Image to Emgu.CV.Image.
i can load my image in formapplication

```
string im_name = str[index];
Emgu.CV.Image<Bgr, Byte> img = new Image<Bgr, byte>(im_name);
```

but this code gives me error of invalid arguments

```
System.Drawing.Image img_btmap = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile( im_name);

Emgu.CV.Image<Bgr, Byte> img1 = new Image<Bgr, byte>(img_btmap);
```

Somebody has idea why???
regards

Comment: care to tell us the error in detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line to:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap img_btmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(im_name);
```

The `Emgu.CV.Image` constructor is expecting Bitmap class which inherits from Image class.

Make sure to dispose img_btmap later otherwise you risk the file being locked.

Edit: most simple way of ensuring proper disposing is using the `using` block like this:

```
using (System.Drawing.Bitmap img_btmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(im_name))
{
   //.....rest of code comes here.....
}
```

Comment: Yup, or just the Image(string) constructor.

Comment: u are right , i have finished it already with [System.Drawing.Bitmap img_btmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(im_name);]and it works but i was expecting other explaination because messagaebox shows already image as bitmap. thanx but what about disposing and dangerof file lock

Comment: @sayyad Bitmap is Image but Image is not Bitmap that's why it didn't work before, regarding disposing see my edit - the "danger" is having the image file locked (e.g. you can't delete it) until garbage collection takes place.